# Jetpack Compose Vertical Grid single item span size

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

In xml you can use GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup in GridLayoutManager to set the span size on single items (How many columns the item will use in the row, like for example, in a grid of 3 columns I can set the first item to be span size 3 so it will use all the width of the grid), but in Compose I can't find a way to do it, the vertical grid only have a way set the global span count and add items, but not set the span size of an individual item, is there a way to do it?

Comment: How did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for this out of the box at present. The way I have solved this for now is to use a `LazyColumn` then the items are `Row`s and in each `Row` you can decide how wide an item is, using `weight`.

I have implemented and in my case I have headers (full width), and cells of items of equal width (based on how wide the screen is, there could be 1, 2 or 3 cells per row).  It's a workaround, but until there is native support from `VerticalGrid` this is an option.

[My solution is here](https://github.com/fvilarino/Weather-Sample/blob/feature/compose/presentation/feature/weather/src/main/java/com/francescsoftware/weathersample/feature/weather/WeatherContent.kt) - look for the `LazyListScope` extensions.

Edit: this is no longer necessary as `LazyVerticalGrid` supports spans now, here's an example

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
    columns = GridCells.Adaptive(
        minSize = WeatherCardWidth,
    ),
    modifier = modifier,
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(all = MarginDouble),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(MarginDouble),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(MarginDouble),
) {
    state.forecastItems.forEach { dayForecast ->
        item(
            key = dayForecast.header.id,
            span = { GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan) }
        ) {
            ForecastHeader(
                state = dayForecast.header,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(vertical = MarginDouble),
            )
        }
        items(
            items = dayForecast.forecast,
            key = { hourForecast -> hourForecast.id }
        ) { hourForecast ->
            ForecastWeatherCard(
                state = hourForecast,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Too bad. Your link doesn't work anymore!

Comment: Link updated, you could clone the project and see how it works. Note that this is no longer necessary though, you can use spans now on lazy grids.

Answer (score 12):

Jetpack Compose version [1.1.0-beta03](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.1.0-beta03) introduced horizontal spans to `LazyVerticalGrid`.

Example code:

```kotlin
val list by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf("A", "E", "I", "O", "U")) }

LazyVerticalGrid(
    cells = GridCells.Fixed(2)
) {
    // Spanned Item:
    item(
        span = {
            // Replace "maxCurrentLineSpan" with the number of spans this item should take.
            // Use "maxCurrentLineSpan" if you want to take full width.
            GridItemSpan(maxCurrentLineSpan)
        }
    ) {
        Text("Vowels")
    }

    // Other items:
    items(list) { item ->
        Text(item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the code from the answer, I created a more "general" purpose method, It can be used with Adaptive and Fixed, I'm very new with Compose so I accept suggestions

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HeaderGrid(cells: GridCells, content: HeaderGridScope.() -> Unit) {
    var columns = 1
    var minColumnWidth = 0.dp
    when (cells) {
        is GridCells.Fixed -> {
            columns = cells.count
            minColumnWidth = cells.minSize
        }
        is GridCells.Adaptive -> {
            val width = LocalContext.current.resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels
            val columnWidthPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { cells.minSize.toPx() }
            minColumnWidth = cells.minSize
            columns = ((width / columnWidthPx).toInt()).coerceAtLeast(1)
        }
    }
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()){
        content(HeaderGridScope(columns, minColumnWidth, this))
    }
}

fun <T>HeaderGridScope.gridItems(items: List<T>, content: @Composable (T) -> Unit) {
    items.chunked(numColumn).forEach {
        listScope.item {
            Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly) {
                it.forEach { 
                    content(it)
                }
                if (it.size < numColumn) {
                    repeat(numColumn - it.size) {
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(columnWidth))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun HeaderGridScope.header(content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit) {
    listScope.item {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
           content = content
        )
    }
}

data class HeaderGridScope(val numColumn: Int, val columnWidth: Dp, val listScope: LazyListScope)

sealed class GridCells {
    class Fixed(val count: Int, val minSize: Dp) : GridCells()
    class Adaptive(val minSize: Dp) : GridCells()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer seems to work but i think it wasn't concise.
Here's how i solved this problem:

```
 LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(count = columns)) {
        myItemsList.forEach { myItem ->
            item(
                key = myItem.hashCode(),
                span = {
                    GridItemSpan(myItem.spanSize)
                }
            ) {
                Text(text=myItem.title)
            }

        }
    }
```

I was building a dynamic app where i was loading list from the firebase. So in these type of scenarios iterating over the list is the best